# Different versions of PowerBI report to different Microsoft team channels

Tags: report, reporting, powerbi, microsoft-teams

I have created a generic report to display statistics about a customer, I have added a report-filter to choose the customer. For each customer I would like to add a report with the filter set to that customer to a specific channel in Microsoft Teams.

For instance: Post a report with filter for CustomerA in the channel called 'CustomerA'. And then also post the same report, but now with filter for CustomerB in the channel 'CustomerB'.

The problem is not so much posting the report (which can be done as a webpage) in the channel, but I was rather wondering: is there a way to easily post different version of my report, with different filter settings, in different Microsoft Teams channels? That is, without having to save and publish each report separately.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: I don't have a workaround myself, but I know passing filter values via URI has been a popular request and is currently being planned - https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6887060-pass-filters-in-url

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, would be a great solution for my problem!